# Virtualization with GPU pass-through on mac

Tags: ubuntu, opencl, gpu, vmware

I'm using VMWare Fusion on my Macbook Pro 15" late 2013 ( i7-4850mq , nvidia 750m ) to virtualize Ubuntu 16.04. I need to use OpenCL inside Ubuntu. I find the way to have it running on CPU but I do not know if there's a way to have it working on the GPU by using a GPU pass-through since the macbook has two GPU (Intel Iris 5200hd and Nvidia 750M ) (if necessary I can switch to another software for virtualization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question belongs more to superuser.com, but anyway you won't be able to do this on a laptop, since even the discrete graphics card is connected to the iGPU via a video mux. Even QEMU with kvm on linux can't do that